# MAAS on Ubuntu Server 12.10 - Node autodetect not enlisting

Tags: 12.10, maas

When I use the Ubuntu server boot media to enlist a new it does not update in the web UI. There is not a `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0/` directory.  And even if I add the node manually via the web UI, with out the tftpboot dir there is no PXE action.

Just a vanilla install of Ubuntu 12.10 on a couple old computers, I had the 12.04 server up and Maas nodes connected and bootstrapped on the same hardware.  just trying to go to 12.10.

I am a novice, but I have ran down a lot of the info on the net so far. I have the quantal images maas-import-pxe-files'ed and the web-ui says the region controller is all good.

I am wondering about any trouble shooting steps i can take to find the tftpboot and or pxe communication issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much more research I found the lack of the tftpboot dir is intentional.  in order to send any kernel options to the node (i.e. noapic nolapic etc) edit 
`/usr/share/pyshared/provisioningserver/kernel_opts.py`
way at the bottom the compose_kernel_command_line method has an options array there.

I ended up running the maas-cli accept-all function to get my node to boot through the default pxe schema. It checked in (I had to accept and commission again) then I was able to get everything bootstrapped and running.